# How to update a value in an arraylist<arraylist<Integer>>

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an array list array list, I am trying to change the value in a specific element, but it tells me that the left hand side must be a variable. I am trying to update using this,

```
list.getMyList().get(4).get(5) = value;
```

Am I doing this incorrect, how would I update that element?

Comment: What is getMyList() here. Please clearly state the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead if you have a 2D ArrayList:

```
arrayLists.get(1).set(index, newValue);
```

Or this if you have a regular ArrayList:

```
arrayList.set(index, newValue);
```